Android app Vertex AI Client Library Auth issue
I am trying to integrate Vertex AI client library to an Android app, but I can't seem to resolve the authentication issue
                                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.IOException: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials for your environment, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc.
I have the service account json, and have setup an env variable in my build.gradle file but nothing seems to work.
Can't find any proper documentation to do this.
My end goal is to create an internal app that talks to vertex ai API using my service account json.
any help will be appreciated.

You may want to provide more detail as to how you are integrating the Vertex AI client library. To my understanding the link in the message only refers to server (local) to server (google) configuration. I believe the Google Java libraries are for OSes with traditional file paths rather than Android's limited access.

As Morrison pointed out, the Java client library is not meant for Android. If you want to use Vertex AI on Android, I'd suggest using Vertex AI for Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/vertex-ai/get-started?platform=android
